# ReactJS seems to turn POST requests into GET requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm using React and the fetch API to do a POST request to a user authentication backend. I can do this POST request below with Postman, and I get the correct JWT back, but oddly - whenever I use the following code in React, the POST request somehow hits the server as a GET request.

Code in React:

```
return this.fetch('http://fakeURL.com/auth', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "email": "email@email.com",
      "password": "password",
    })
}).then(res => {
    this.setToken(res.token);
    return Promise.resolve(res);
})
```

The logs show (first the pre-flight request):

> Request URL: http‍://fakeURL.com/auth
> Request Method: OPTIONS
> Status Code: 200 OK
> Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

And the actual request:

> Request URL: http‍://fakeURL.com/auth
> Request Method: GET
> Status Code: 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED
> Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Things I've tried:

- Running the app both locally and in an AWS S3 bucket (with CORS configured to allow all methods, and from any origin)
- Using Flask on our backend to enable CORS
- Hitting our backend via Postman with the same API POST request (when we use Postman, the API request works as intended, as a POST that returns a token)
- Hitting other URLs (e.g. http://httpbin.org/post) to see if my code can hit those endpoints with a POST rather than a GET... and those endpoints see GET requests as well (instead of the intended POST)

This is so confusing - what could possibly cause our POST request to go out as a GET request? I feel like we've eliminated every possibly cause outside of something weird happening in React.

Comment: Why do you do `this.fetch`? What is `this` there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm install --save axios

on your auth page:
import axios from 'axios'

Modify your post so instead of using fetch:

```
login(emailValue, passwordValue) {
    return axios({
        url: `yourAuthURL`,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        data: {
          "email": emailValue,
          "password": passwordValue,
        }
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
}
```